# Django form: object has no attribute

Tags: python, django

I have the form that looks like this:

```
class PeopleForm(forms.Form):
  adult = forms.IntegerField(min_value=1, initial=1)
  children = forms.IntegerField(min_value=0, required = False)
```

The quantity of this form depend on value of other field in other form. So I create formset for this form in the view. In the final result, I need to get to the field `adult` of the forms `PeopleForm` and create the string that should look like this `Adult=2, Adult=3`.

So my view looks like this:

```
PeopleFormSet = formset_factory(PeopleForm, extra = 1, max_num = 15)
people_formset = PeopleFormSet(request.POST, prefix='people')
  if people_formset.is_valid():
    adults = ''
    for i in people_formset:
      adults = i.adult
```

But I've got an error `'PeopleForm' object has no attribute 'adult'`. I don't understand how  to get to the field `adult` of `people_formset`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the value from the form's [`cleaned_data`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.cleaned_data).

```
for form in people_formset:
    adults = form.cleaned_data['adult']
```

Comment: Isn't the `save` method only available on a `ModelForm`?

Comment: @Ben, you're right, I didn't spot that `PeopleForm` is a regular form. I've removed that part of the answer.